# DXA Model Extension: Is it not Open Source?

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, model-service, extension-model

Source code of (legacy) SDL Model service is available on GitHub: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service

Since this model service functionality is now provided by the GraphQL Content Service as the DXA Model Extension.

But I can't find the source code of Model extension on GitHub, is it not meant to be open source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, DXA Model Extension is currently not Open Source.

That may well change in the future, though.

Comment: Thanks @Rick, hopefully it happens soon.